# Mystery about $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^{-n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I was playing with some series when [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1367773959673&i=%5Csum_%7Bn=1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%202%5E%7B-n!%7D&fp=1&incTime=true) told me that 
$$\sum_{n\geqslant 1}2^{-n!}=0.765625059604644775390625\color{Red}{000000000000}752316384526264\ldots$$
and my eyes obviously stopped at the red area. Twelve decimal places! Similarly, $$\begin{align} \sum_{n\geqslant 1}4^{-n!} &= 0.31274414(\cdots)1337890625\color{Red}{000000000000000000000000}565979\ldots \\
\sum_{n\geqslant 1}8^{-n!} &= 0.140628814(\cdots)625\color{Red}{000000000000000000000000000000000000}42579598\ldots \end{align}$$
where I omitted $30$ digits and $60$ digits respectively. Is it a coincidence or is there a deeper reason? Why are these numbers so well approximated?

Comment: Try writing the first in binary the second in base four and the third in base 8.

Comment: I see, it is quite similar to $\sum_{k\geqslant 1}10^{-k!}$. However, I don't see a connection between this and the 12 zeroes in  base ten in the examples above.

Comment: Intuitively what I think is happening is that in base two you have these large oceans of zeros. It seems to me that when one changes to base ten, a sizable proportion of the zeros will survive. The comment also tells us why these numbers have such good rational aproximations.

Comment: To mention a fact explained in the comments below, $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}k^{-n!}$ has "longer and longer bunches of consecutive zeroes" for every $k\geqslant2$, $k=2^i5^j$.

Comment: IanMateus As a "typical teenager" (your profile), could you explain why you accepted the accepted answer? For the example in the first paragraph? For the second paragraph? For both?

Comment: @Did I accepted it because I considered it cleaner and more helpful than the other answer, which is a comparison involving other series. The last edit also made it better.

Comment: "Cleaner and more helpful" to explain the gaps in the decimal expansion? [I doubt that](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRLNdcmRcFY)... (For the record, @Hagen's answer mentions the crucial arguments.) Anyway, now the explanation is in the comments, and even in the answer, so everything is fine.

Comment: @BabyDragon, it would seem so, but I tested and it relates to the fact 2 is a factor of 10. It works for 5 as well, and I suspect, for any factor of any base.

Comment: @JMCF125 You could see that the fact that this will work for other bases by adapting the argument given in Hagen von Eitzen's answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the first, note that: 
$$
\begin{align} 
2^{-1!} + 2^{-2!} + 2^{-3!} + 2^{-4!} &= 
0.765625059604644775390625\color{red}{000000000000}000000\ldots \\
2^{-5!} &= 
0.000000000000000000000000\color{red}{000000000000}752316\ldots 
\end{align}
$$
So the reason you get a bunch of zeros at this point is that $2^{-5!} = 2^{-120}$ is several orders of magnitude smaller than $2^{-4!} = 2^{-24}$. In particular, $2^{-24}$ has at most $24$ non-zero digits, which means all digits after the $24$th will be zero, while $2^{-120} < 10^{-36}$, which means the first $36$ digits of $2^{-5!}$ will be $0$. So adding them up leaves a gap of $12$ zeros.

Note that, although slightly hidden, this is *not* the first sequence of zeros that appears for the reason mentioned above, as the $7$th digit is a $0$ for the same reason: that $2^{-3!}$ is much bigger than $2^{-4!}$.
$$
\begin{align} 
2^{-1!} &= 
0.500000000000000000000000000000000000000000\ldots \\
2^{-2!} &= 
0.250000000000000000000000000000000000000000\ldots \\
2^{-3!} &= 
0.015625\color{red}{0}00000000000000000000000000000000000\ldots \\
2^{-4!} &= 
0.000000\color{red}{0}59604644775390625\color{red}{000000000000}000000\ldots \\
2^{-5!} &= 
0.000000000000000000000000\color{red}{000000000000}752316\ldots \\ 
& \vdots \\ \hline
\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^{-n!} &= 
0.765625\color{red}{0}59604644775390625\color{red}{000000000000}752316\ldots
\end{align}
$$
The gaps will get bigger and bigger as you move to the right. For instance, starting at the $121$st digit, there will be a huge gap until the $\lceil\log_{10}(2^{6!})\rceil = 216$th digit.

For completeness, as pointed out in the comments by @Did, the reason that you get such gaps *at all* is that $2 \mid 10$ (or more precisely: all prime divisors of $2$ divide $10$), which means that the decimal expansions of $2^{-k!}$ always terminate, i.e., always have a finite number of non-zero digits in its decimal expansion. And because $n!$ grows ridiculously fast, you then get long strings of zeros.

Comment: *So the reason you get a bunch of zeros is that... is several orders of magnitudes smaller than...* Sorry but I do not think this is the reason. Otherwise the same argument would apply to $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}7^{-n!}$, which has no two consecutive digits $0$ amongst its $110+$ first digits.

Comment: @Did: Sure, if $2$ was coprime to $10$, we would have a problem. So yes, the reason that you may possibly get strings of zeros *at all* is that the decimal expansions terminate, but the reason that this gap appears *at this point, and has length $12$*, is what I described above.

Comment: The same applies to $6$ instead of $7$, and $6$ is not coprime to $10$ hence coprimality to $10$ is moot here... // If the fact that the expansion of $\frac12$ terminates is crucial (and it is), THIS fact should be mentioned as a reason in any answer (and then, the observation that the bunch-of-zeroes phenomenon occurs for $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}k^{-n!}$ if and only if $k\geqslant2$ with $k=2^i5^j$, would be right around the corner...).

Answer (score 11):

Note that $2^{-k}=5^k\cdot 10^{-k}$, so that is a number with $\approx \log_{10}5^k=k\log_{10}5\approx 0.7k$ nonzero digits and a total of $k$ digits. In other words: $2^{-k}$ starts with $\approx 0.3k$ zeroes. Your exponents $k=n!$ grow quite fast, so that sooner or later $0.3(n+1)!$ is much bigger than $n!$, thus leading to large blocks of zeroes.